# 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
private void Right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
   using (var ctx = new NORTHWNDEntities())
   {
       if (currentIndex < ctx.Employees.Count())
       {
           currentIndex++;
           Employee empl = ctx.Employees.ToList().ElementAt(currentIndex);


           Id.Text = empl.EmployeeID.ToString();
           FirstName.Text = empl.FirstName;
           LastName.Text = empl.LastName;
           DateOfBirth.Text = empl.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
       }
       else
       {
           Load();
       }
   }
}
```

So I have to iterate through this collection, but when I get to the end of collection I get this exception. Can someone tell me why my if block do not stop that kind of exception? Thanks

Comment: You should increment the value of `currentIndex` then check if it's less than `ctx.Employees.Count()`

Answer (score 2):

Move your increment after the array access.
You encountered the exception because you are trying to access a memory that is not part of the memory allocated for your array.

```
private void Right_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    using (var ctx = new NORTHWNDEntities())
    {


        if (currentIndex < ctx.Employees.Count())
        {
            Employee empl = ctx.Employees.ToList().ElementAt(currentIndex);


            Id.Text = empl.EmployeeID.ToString();
            FirstName.Text = empl.FirstName;
            LastName.Text = empl.LastName;
            DateOfBirth.Text = empl.BirthDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
            currentIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            Load();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

perform `currentIndex++;`

after   `Employee empl = ctx.Employees.ToList().ElementAt(currentIndex);`